# Tensorflow.js multi-variable fitting of a function with 6 parameters

Tags: javascript, math, regression, tensorflow.js

I would like to ask for some help.

My goal is to determine, using a nonlinear regression method in tensorflow.js, the values of 6 parameters in a function from R^2 -> R (which therefore has two independent variables, x1 and x2).

Is it possible to use TensorFlow to achieve this result?

By now I wrote this script:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

    

  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>Tensorflow.js<hr/></h4>
    
        <script>
    
    // Create a simple model.




const x1 = tf.tensor2d([10, 11, 12], [3, 1]);
const x2 = tf.tensor2d([8, 21, 4], [3, 1]);
const y = tf.tensor2d([8, 21, 4], [3, 1]);

function Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y) {
    [r1_i, r2_i, s_i, t1_i, t2_i, t3_i] = initial_params;
    const Vrev = tf.scalar(1.0);
    const A = tf.scalar(1.0);
    const r1 = tf.variable(tf.scalar(r1_i));
    const r2 = tf.variable(tf.scalar(r2_i));
    const s = tf.variable(tf.scalar(s_i));
    const t1 = tf.variable(tf.scalar(t1_i));
    const t2 = tf.variable(tf.scalar(t2_i));
    const t3 = tf.variable(tf.scalar(t3_i));

    const Blocco1 = tf.div(Vrev, A);
    const Blocco2 = tf.add(r1, tf.mul(r2, x2));
    const Blocco3 = tf.mul(Blocco1, Blocco2, x1);
    const Blocco4 = tf.mul(Blocco3, s);
    const Blocco5 = tf.div(t2, x1);
    const Blocco6 = tf.div(t3, tf.pow(x1, 2));
    const Blocco7 = tf.add(t1, Blocco5)
    const Blocco8 = tf.add(Blocco7, Blocco6);
    const Blocco9 = tf.log(tf.add(Blocco8, 1));
    const funzione = tf.add(Blocco4, Blocco9);

    const error = tf.losses.meanSquaredError(funzione.arraySync(), y.arraySync()).arraySync();
    return error;
}

const initial_params = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0];



console.log(Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y));

const result = tf.train.minimize(() => Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y), true);
console.log(result);
const optimizedParams = result.x.arraySync();
console.log("Optimized Params:", optimizedParams);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get: Uncaught TypeError: tf.train.minimize is not a function

How could I do now to calculate the six parameters?

Just to be more clear: I have the following function:[Function with parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWPMf.png)

I then have a daset made by Vrev, I and T, and I want to find the parameters that perfectly fit the function

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing the code myself, without using TensorFlow.
Honestly, the documentation is very poor and using a library that complicates things instead of simplifying them is counterproductive.

Instructions for use

The code can be modified by renaming the occurrence "Ulberg" everywhere and inserting the function name of your choice. Of course, the function itself must also be changed.

If you want to increase or decrease the number of parameters simply start the code with an initial_params vector with a different number of "1".

The vectors x1, x2,… xn, y can have the size you prefer depending on your dataset, as long as they are homogeneous with each other.

No code changes are needed other than adding or removing parameters in the "ulberg" function.

```
        <script>
function Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y) {
    result = [];
    if(!((x1.length == x2.length) || (x2.length == y.length))){
    console.log("I vettori hanno grandezze diverse");
    }
    const [r1_i, r2_i, s_i, t1_i, t2_i, t3_i] = initial_params;
    const Vrev = 12;
    const A = 1;

    const r1 = r1_i;
    const r2 = r2_i;
    const s  = s_i ;
    const t1 = t1_i;
    const t2 = t2_i;
    const t3 = t3_i;
    // Prima elaborazione
    for(i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
        //Funzione completa
        const valore_funzione = (Vrev) + ((r1 + r2*x1[i])/A)*x2[i] + s*Math.log10(1 + ((t1 + (t2/x1[i]) + (t3/(x1[i]*x1[i])))/A)*x2[i]);
        result.push(valore_funzione);
    }
    //console.log(result);
    //console.log("Sono stata eseguita");
    return result;
}

    
function meanSquaredError(actual, experimental){
        if(!(actual.length == experimental.length)){
    console.log("I vettori hanno grandezze diverse, impossibile determinare il mean squared error.");
    }
    error = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < actual.length; i++){
            error += Math.pow((actual[i] - experimental[i]), 2);
            //console.log("Errore parziale");
            //console.log(error);
    }   

    
    return error/actual.length;
}


function addVector(a, b){
    return a.map((e,i) => e + b[i]);
}

function subtractVector(a, b){
    return a.map((e,i) => e - b[i]);
}

function multiplyVector(a, b){
    return a.map((e,i) => e * b[i]);
}

function divideVector(a, b){
    return a.map((e,i) => e / b[i]);
}

function elevateVector(a, power){
    return a.map((e,i) => Math.pow(e, power));
}

function sqrtVector(a){
    return a.map((e,i) => Math.sqrt(e));
}

function multiplyScalar(a, vector){
    return vector.map((e,i) => e * a);
}

/* Your data. Please make sure that all vectors have the same dimension */
const x1 = [55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55];
const x2 = [0.001256,0.007716,0.01337,0.019026,0.027493,0.033133,0.050034,0.066534,0.086245,0.105553,0.125261,0.156229,0.189204,0.232631,0.265603,0.28812,0.32109,0.345216,0.377782,0.410752,0.433669,0.467039,0.488748];
const y = [15.5113,16.3797,17.1882,18.0416,18.8204,19.2249,19.8249,20.4399,20.9205,21.386,21.8068,22.3632,22.8748,23.4324,23.8543,24.1107,24.4727,24.7592,25.0613,25.4084,25.6349,25.9222,26.0588];


const h = 0.01;
const lambda = 0.01;
const beta1 = 0.9;
const beta2 = 0.999;

const noi = 100000; /*  Number of iterations */


//let initial_params =      [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ];

let m =             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let v =             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let m_hat =             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let v_hat =             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let epsilon =           [0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001];

/* Se vuoi ottenere l'immagine della funzione */
//console.log(Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y));

var empty_array = [];
var explore_params = [];
var gradient = [];
//Calcolo le derivate parziali
console.log(Ulberg(initial_params, [55], [0.5], [9999999]));

for(j = 0; j < noi; j++){
    for(t = 0; t < initial_params.length; t++){
    //console.log(initial_params.length);
        explore_params = initial_params.slice();
        explore_params[t] = explore_params[t] + h;
y) - meanSquaredError(Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y), y))/h);
        gradient.push(     ((meanSquaredError(Ulberg(explore_params, x1, x2, y), y) - meanSquaredError(Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y), y))/h )        );
        }

    m = addVector(multiplyScalar(beta1, m), multiplyScalar((1 - beta1), gradient));
    v = addVector(multiplyScalar(beta2, v), multiplyScalar((1 - beta2), multiplyVector(gradient, gradient)));
    
    m_hat.slice();
    v_hat.slice();
    
    m_hat = multiplyScalar((1/(1 - Math.pow(beta1, j+1))), m);
    v_hat = multiplyScalar((1/(1 - Math.pow(beta2, j+1))), v);

    initial_params = subtractVector(initial_params, divideVector(multiplyScalar(lambda, m_hat), addVector(epsilon, elevateVector(v_hat, 0.5))));
    
    /*for(k = 0; k < initial_params.length; k++){
        initial_params[k] = initial_params[k] - Math.random() * lambda * gradient[k];
        }
        */
    gradient = empty_array.slice();
    console.log("Sto per stampare i parametri iniziali modificati:");
    console.log(initial_params);
    console.log("Errore:");
    console.log(meanSquaredError(Ulberg(initial_params, x1, x2, y), y));
}
```

Interestingly, without using an ADAM optimizer the code failed to converge.